# if else change declared variable in database SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to change the value of already declared variable.
I want to update something in my table base on the declared variable.

what I've tried so far

```
  IF NOT EXISTS                                   
  (SELECT  1 FROM [DB_databaseOne].[dbo].[data_tblOne]                                      
    WHERE orderBy= 'AC038234'             
    and prodCode = 'P0008'            
    and batchID = '1'                        
    and is_buy = 3 and voidFlag is null)
     BEGIN
          DECLARE @MSG VARCHAR(300) = 'GOOD'
     END
  ELSE
     BEGIN 
          DECLARE @MSG VARCHAR(300) = 'NOT GOOD'
     END
```

Comment: Like any variable you need to declare it outside the current scope, set it where you are currently declaring it, and print it after your if

Comment: As you have it written now, you don't even need a variable, just ordered not the string directly.

Comment: What's not working about your current code?

Comment: Based on the use on the `dbo` (schema?) and brackets (`[]`) to delimit identify this looks like SQL Server, *not* MySQL. If you *are* using MySQL, then you're going to get syntax errors.

Comment: As for how to assign a value to a variable, See [SET @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I want to update table based on my variable if it is possible to do. As you can see on my example. the second variable is not working, 

"The variable name '@msg' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `DECLARE` your variable only once.  You can have multiple `SET` statements to assign a value:

```
DECLARE @MSG VARCHAR(300)   

IF NOT EXISTS                                   
  (SELECT  1 FROM [DB_databaseOne].[dbo].[data_tblOne]                                      
    WHERE orderBy= 'AC038234'             
    and prodCode = 'P0008'            
    and batchID = '1'                        
    and is_buy = 3 and voidFlag is null)
     BEGIN
          SET @MSG =  'GOOD'
          PRINT @MSG
     END
  ELSE
     BEGIN 
          SET @MSG = 'NOT GOOD'
          PRINT @MSG
     END
```

Comment: So I only need "set" to change the variable? Appreciate it sir!